# How to encrypt image using a password preferably using AES or simple encryption in laravel

Tags: laravel, image, encryption

I am making an application , which requires images to be encrypted using password ,and same password is used while decryption all this using AES algorightm in laravel. There are modules available but they work without encrypting the image using password.

can anybody help

Comment: It depends on what exactly you need. For example, you can upload image file to the server and create row in database related to this file. If user puts correct password, you're making temporary link to this file. Or you can store encrypted file on disk or in the database directly and decrypt it after user puts password.

Comment: @SergeyShitikov. Thanks for the comment. Actually i want much like second part of your suggestion.beside i dont want any interference of database , i just want a "string" or a password (salt) to encrypt the image and while decryption , using the same salt . Is there any thing available in laravel?